# How to crawl multiple links in Scrapy following an xpath-based rule in the given start page?

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I have created a spider that successfully extract the data I want from a single page, now I need it to crawl multiple similar pages and do the same.

The start page is going to be [this one](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/List_of_unique_accessories), here there are listed many unique item from the game (Araku tiki, sidhbreath etc), I want the spider to crawl all those items.

Given that as a start page, how to identifies which links to follow?

Here are the xpaths for the first 3 links i want it to follow:

```
//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/span/span[1]/a[1]
//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/span/span[1]/a[1]
//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/span/span[1]/a[1]
```

As you can see there is an increasing number in the middle, 1, then 2, then 3 and so on. How to crawl those pages?

Here is a snippet of my code working for the first item, Araku Tiki, having its page set as start:

```
import scrapy
from PoExtractor.items import PoextractorItem
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class RedditSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "arakaali"
  #  allowed_domains = ['pathofexile.gamepedia.com']
    start_urls = ['https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Araku_Tiki']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=()), callback="parse",
             follow=True),
    )



    def parse(self, response):
            item = PoextractorItem()
            item["item_name"] = response.xpath("//*[@id='mw-content-text']/span/span[1]/span[1]/text()[1]").extract()
            item["flavor_text"] = response.xpath("//*[@id='mw-content-text']/span/span[1]/span[2]/span[3]/text()").extract()
            yield item
```

Please note: I have not be able to make it follow all the links in the start page either, my code only works if the start page is the one contained the requested data.

Thanks in advance for every reply.

Comment: does it need to follow inner links to find more weapons (like Araku, etc.) or just the ones listed on the page you posted?

Comment: It need to enter the link located into the xpath previously posted and get data from those pages. Each of those links opens a page of a piece of gear of the game, here i need to get name and flavor text of it.

In the start page are contained all the links I need to enter, and they are contained into the paths I posted on the question, hope I clarified it well enough, let me know if otherwise!

Comment: ok, so I just can tell you that you should follow the tutorial here https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/ and improve your xpaths (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp). The question looks to be more about requesting work to be done instead of just help with coding problems. Please check the topics that can be asked in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I sure lack lot of knowledge but I turned to stackoverflow after hours of attempt in a matter where I am not proficient. I tried countless combinations, getting to internal links, to every link, doing xpath by hand, by tools online, by inspect in chrome, I even tried to crawl all the links and feed them to another spider: nothing worked. I feel the judgement and the following downvote are unfair, could have at least pointed me toward something after doing reputation damage which was undeserved and really weights for new users. Nonetheless I still appreciated the reason for the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can send requests in many ways.

> 1.Since you are using scrapy, the following code can be used

```
def parse_page1(self, response):
    return scrapy.Request("http://www.example.com/some_page.html",
                          callback=self.parse_page2)

def parse_page2(self, response):
    # this would log http://www.example.com/some_page.html
    self.logger.info("Visited %s", response.url)
```

parse_page1 will send requests to the url and you will get the response in parse_page2 function.

> 2.You can even send requests using python requests module,

```
import requests
resp = req.get("http://www.something.com")

print(resp.text)
```

Please comment if you have any doubt regarding this, thank you